# What do the abbreviations BB, SB and D mean in Texas Hold 'Em?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

http://www.flopturnriver.com/Holdem-Expected-Value-10-Players.php

Maybe D is dealer and B is blind, but what is BB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BB = Big Blind

SB = Small Blind

D = Dealer